# Select ALL elements with specific data attribute Javascript?

Tags: javascript, attributes

With jquery, I've got the following code:

`$('a[data-hello]').click(function(){` = **That select all "a" elements with "data-hello".**

I'm trying to make this with raw Javascript. I stop here:

`document.querySelectorAll("data-hello").onclick = function() {`

*(btw, theres a way to select all the A elements with data-hello and not all with data-hello? o.O)*

But `querySelectorAll` returns a Array. Because of this, it only works  if I determine a position.  This way:

`document.querySelectorAll("data-hello")[5].onclick = function() {`

But I want **ALL ELEMENTS**, not specific elements, like with jQuery. I cant use jQuery.

It is so simple with Jquery :( I must make a "for" to wade through all the positions in JS? Is this necessary? sorry I do not understand...

---

**What I want to do:**

I want to get the data attribute value of the element that is clicked. I use `this` for this inside the function and, then, I applied another function that add a class in a specific element.
Basically, there is buttons with classes in data attribute value. This classes will be applied to a specific element.

Comment: _"But `querySelectorAll` returns a Array."_ - No it doesn't, it returns a NodeList. (Which yes, you would then have to loop through - which is what jQuery methods like `.click()` do behind the scenes.)

Comment: And what's the difference between a nodelist and array? :S

Comment: The difference between an Array and a NodeList? Well, the main difference that you need to know about is that a NodeList doesn't have Array methods like `.pop()`, `.forEach()`, etc. (A NodeList is an array-like object, so you can use some array methods via `Array.prototype` and `.call()` or `.apply()`.)

Comment: Unfortunately, `NodeList` isn't a fully-fledged Array, which caught me out. [This Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_can't_I_use_forEach_or_map_on_a_NodeList.3F) explains it very well. Btw, googling `mdn <html|css|javascript term>` is a great way to begin debugging - I do so thousands of times a day =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the array (actually a NodeList) of elements in a variable and loop through them to set the event handler on each of them. That's what the jQuery methods do to apply something to all elements in a jQuery object. There is no way around the loop, with jQuery it's just hidden within the methods. You can use the same selector syntax as in jQuery with `querySelectorAll`.

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-hello]");
var f = function() {
  // do something
};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i].onclick = f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` accepts a string of comma-separated CSS selectors, just like jQuery, so you can give it the same string: `'a[data-hello]'`.

The difference between native and jQuery that you are running into is in calling methods on the elements returned. jQuery returns a jQuery **object**, which has methods that often loop over all the elements, `.click()` being one such methods. You need to replicate that with the **array** of elements that `querySelectorAll` is returning by looping over the array and applying the same handler to each element's `onclick` property.

Try this:

```js
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-hello]");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(myElements, function (element) {
    element.onclick = function () {
        // Your onclick handler code goes here.
        console.log('clicked', element);
    };
});
```

Comment: `NodeList` has no method `forEach`.

Comment: Right you are - forgot about that! I use abstraction libraries like lodash so regularly. Fixed it now =)

Comment: @SergeiZahharenko Thanks! Do you mean this bit? `Array.prototype.forEach.call`

Comment: Wow! So different.. Thank you, Henry, really! Thanks for explaining too! Happy new year!

Comment: Note: The `forEach` method doesn't exist in older browsers, like IE8.

Comment: You're welcome Pedro! Thanks Sergei - I agree! However, like Guffa correctly pointed out, `forEach` is supported less than `querySelectorAll`, so a `for` loop is best really =) Always nice to educate about using `call` and `apply` to use class methods though!

Answer (score 0):

as simple as that:

```
var dataElems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-hello]")
for (var i=0;i<dataElems.length;i++) { 
    dataElems[i].onclick = function(i,v) {
        alert(this.innerHTML)        
    }
}
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/W86k8/

Comment: This dont works for me. 

"But querySelectorAll returns a Array. Because of this, it only works if I determine a position."

Comment: @PedroMelo you know you can just iterate through each element, which is what jquery does. `document.querySelectorAll("[data-hello]").forEach(function(v) { v.onclick = function() {}});`

Comment: @DarrenKopp Unfortunately your code won't work, for the same reason mine didn't at first: `forEach` isn't a method of `NodeList`, which `querySelectorAll` returns. It's a sorry state of affairs for chaining methods =(